# entity framework compare in memory entity to saved entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've simplified my code to better illustrate my point.  I need to have some business logic where I test if a property has changed from a to b.  The problem that I'm facing is that the entity that I am manipulating is attached to my DBContext.  If I update the property on one of my references the other is also updated:

```
  ....
  var oldEntity = context.Find(x);
  var updatedEntity = context.Find(x);

  //here updatedEntity.IntProperty is 6

  updatedEntity.IntProperty = 7;

  //here both oldEntity.IntProperty and updatedEntity.IntProperty 
  //are now 7 so my test isn't hit
  if(oldEntity.IntProperty != updatedEntity.IntProperty && 
      updatedEntity.IntProperty == 7)
  {
      ....
```

Is there some convenient way to do the comparison I want while leaving this entity attached to the DBContext?

Comment: You might want to look at the ObjectStateManager.  It caches the properties that were loaded.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.aspx

Comment: I am using DBContext not ObjectContext.  Is there a way to access ObjectStateManager from DBContext?

Comment: @BenTidman Cast your DbContext to IObjectContextAdapter which has the underlying ObjectContext and then use its property ObjectStateManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Entity Framework for nHydrate.  The principal will be the same (this is VB.NET sorry!):

```
Dim initialEntity = _context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry((TryCast(oldEntity, Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithKey)).EntityKey)

Dim oldValue As Integer = initialEntity.OriginalValues.GetValue("IntProperty")
Dim newValue As Integer = initialEntity.CurrentValues.GetValue("IntProperty")
```

Hope this helps.

Andez

Comment: Is it possible to look at a specific property?  Can you provide an example of how to do that?